# mysql database Back-up (linux server to client m/c) automatically

Tags: php

How can we store the mysql database Back-up from a linux server to a client windows m/c automatically in a fixed duration of time...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "guarantee" that the backup will be saved in a fixed amount of time. If you setup a share to a folder on the windows machine you can have a cron job backup the database and save it to the share at a specific start time. But it depends on the size of the backup how long it takes to create and copy/move the backup to the share.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote these scripts to backup a mysql database.

http://codingsnippets.com/category/mysql/

They'll have to be called from a cron job to do it regularly.

http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference

If you want to create a windows share on the windows box, you can mount it from linux with a command like this:

```
mount -t smbfs -o username=bjones //192.168.1.100/"Storage (H)" /mnt/windows-storage/
```

Good luck